How to get users presence status and number of users available in a specific queue?
How can I retrieve the presence status of a specific D365 User?
How can I retrieve the number of users available in a specific queue?
I have the User-ID and the Queue-ID available but can't make it.
I tried to get the number of available Agents with this:
GET https://{myorg}.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/queueitems?$filter=_queueid_value eq {myqueue} and statecode eq 0&$select=_workerid_value

Answer (even if a minimum of one Agent is available):
{
    "@odata.context": "https://{myorg}.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/$metadata#queueitems(_workerid_value)",
    "value": []
}


You can get user presence status with Microsoft Graph API. And get queue member with a fetchXML as Queue has an N:N relationship with SystemUser.

How do you define an available user? Precense & capacity? Do you take a queue working hours into consideration? Are you using Omnichannel? Do you use Unified Routing? Do you want to emulate its behaviour? If you add more details on the end goal I may provide more specific help.
